# i have a problem to make list in django shell

Tags: django-views

> | header 1 | header 2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | cell 1 | cell 2 |
> | cell 3 | cell 4 |
>
> | header 1 | header 2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | cell 1 | cell 2 |
> | cell 3 | cell 4 |
>
> 1. ---
>
>    i try to make a member list and i got this error>> member1=member(firstname='mancham',lastname='weiss')

> > > member2=member(firstname='mendel',lastname='weiss')
> > > member3m=member(firstname='tovya',lastname='weiss')
> > > members_list=[member1,member2,member3]
> > > for x in members_list:
> > > ... x.save
> > > File "<console>", line 2
> > > x.save
> > > ^
> > > IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 1
>
> > > for x in members_list
> > > File "<console>", line 1
> > > for x in members_list
> > > ^
> > > SyntaxError: expected ':'
>
> > > for x in members_list:
> > > ... x.save()
> > > File "<console>", line 2
> > > x.save()
> > > ^
> > > IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 1

> > member1=member(firstname='mancham',lastname='weiss')
> >
> > > member2=member(firstname='mendel',lastname='weiss')
> > > member3m=member(firstname='tovya',lastname='weiss')
> > > members_list=[member1,member2,member3]
> > > for x in members_list:x.save()
> > > ...
> > > File "<console>", line 2
> > > x.save
> > > ^
> > > IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 1
>
> > > for x in members_list
> > > File "<console>", line 1
> > > for x in members_list
> > > ^
> > > SyntaxError: expected ':'
>
> > > for x in members_list:
> > > ... x.save()
> > > File "<console>", line 2
> > > x.save()
> > > ^
> > > IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'for' statement on line 1

Answer (score 0):

model = Person

```
person1= Person(firstname='sahil', lastname= 'desai')
person2= person(firstname= 'nk', lastname='ba')

person_list = [person1,person2]
for x in person_list:
     x.save()
```

**when you Show all member details.**

```
Person.objects.all().values()
```